# Jquery mobile gives error when refreshing, but not when initially opening the file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

When I open the file in chrome, It works how it should but refreshing the page gives me an error. I have already checked that I am not listing the same sources twice. Very weird if you ask me!

this is the error I am getting:

Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on popup prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'open'

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>jQuery Mobile Example</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <div data-role="popup" id="intro_view" data-overlay-theme="a" data-theme="a" style="max-width:100%;">
            <div data-role="header" data-theme="a" class="ui-corner-top ui-header ui-bar-a" role="banner">
                <h1 class="ui-title" role="heading" aria-level="1">Welcome!</h1>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content" data-theme="d" class="ui-corner-bottom ui-content ui-body-d" role="main">
                <h1 class="ui-title">Navigate through time and space to see what's happening around you!</h1>
                <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Here's a few quick tips to get you started:</p>
                <ol>
                <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-rel="back" data-theme="c" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" class="ui-btn ui-btn-up-c ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-inline"><span class="ui-btn-inner"><span class="ui-btn-text">Cancel</span></span></a>    
                <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-rel="back" data-transition="flow" data-theme="b" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" class="ui-btn ui-btn-up-b ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-inline"><span class="ui-btn-inner"><span class="ui-btn-text">Delete</span></span></a>  
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>          
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $( "#intro_view" ).popup( "open",{positionTo:"window"} );
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of $(document).ready .. use this

```
$(document).bind('pageinit', function() {
$("#intro_view").popup('open');
```

});

Please refer jquery docs http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/docs/api/events.html

Comment: Thank you for the response, I tried this and it is still not working. Now it's giving me the error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'is' of undefined